# watchOS 4 not measuring resting or walking heart rate

Tags: apple-watch, health.app, watchos, activity.app

The description of new features available in watchOS (and the Heart features in iOS 11's Health app) mention "Resting" and "Walking" rates. In fact the [official description](https://www.apple.com/watchos/) suggests that the Watch Heart app should be measuring these new categories:

[image]

But I don't see any measurements of these categories at all (after several days of lots of resting and walking), nor do I even see Watch listed among the relevant sources in Health on iOS.

Are these features actually available? Are they only available on certain Watch models?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported by the original Apple Watch (2015).

It's mentioned in the first paragraph - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204666

> Resting and walking rates are available only on Apple Watch Series 1 or later.

Only Apple Watch **Series 1/Series 2 (2016) and Series 3 (2017)** provide information about resting and walking heart rates.

See also [The Verge's article regarding watchOS 4's heart rate features with the original Apple Watch](https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/21/16347244/apple-watch-os-4-heart-rate-series-original).

Comment: Do you know by chance if the newer watches do a better job with heart rate? The original's measurements are essentially random.